# Twitter - How to embed native video from someone else's tweet into a New Tweet or a DM

Tags: video, twitter

There used to be a way to extract the **Twitter Card** of a tweet containing a **Native Video** (to get video's: `amp.twimg.com` link). Obtaining this link enabled, in turn, to copy&paste it into another tweet and have the video from the original tweet play natively in the new tweet or even send a native video in a direct message or schedule a tweet with a native video using 3rd party apps. It seems like the `amp.twimg.com` link is deprecated. Anyone knows an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a faster way of embedding:

- Just copy the link.
- Paste the link and remove the "?s=19" part and add "/video/1"
- That's it.

Comment: Thanks, a decent way to do it.

Comment: Note that this only works on the original tweet for the video! If someone else shared the video (it says "From <account name>"), it won't work. On web, you can use the embed answer. On Android, long-press the tweet to copy the text, then the video URL is at the end. On iOS I think you can copy directly.

Answer (score 7):

I eventually figured out an easy way to do it:

1. On your Twitter feed, click the date/time of the tweet containing the video. That will open the single tweet view
2. Look for the down-pointing arrow at the top-right corner of the tweet, click it to open drop-down menue
3. Select the "Embed Video" option and copy the HTML embed code and Paste it to Notepad
4. Find the last "t.co" shortened URL inside the HTML code (should be something like this: ``` https://``t.co/tQM43ftXyM ```). Copy this URL and paste it in a new browser tab.
5. The browser will expand the shortened URL to something which looks like this: `https://twitter.com/UserName/status/828267001496784896/video/1`

This is the link to the Twitter Card containing the native video. Pasting this link in a new tweet or DM will include the native video in it!